# Java regex for a given output

Tags: java, regex

I have the next given output:

```
1:      IP4 1.1.1.1         255.0.0.0       1.255.255.255    
127:    IP6 fd55:faaf:e1ab:215d:0:0:0:103/64               
         fe80::7699:75ff:fec8:427e
128:    IP4 10.241.6.103    255.255.255.128 10.241.6.127
```

I want a regex that will match lines 1,2 and 3 and will not match third line.

Regex should sound like this:

Line must start with a number between 0 and 999 followed by `:`, then some white spaces followed by `IP4` or `IP6` word and the rest of the line until `"\n"` doesn't matter.

Comment: So you want two problems?

Comment: @chrylis where is my second problem?

Comment: Something like `/^\d{1,3}:\s+IP[46]/`?

Comment: @PhilippPalmtag, this question already has a chosen answer. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
\d{1,3}:\s+IP[46].*[0-9]
```

Simply explained:

- `\d{1,3}` matches a number with 1, 2 or 3 digits (0-999)
- `:` matches `:` literally
- `\s+` matches at leas one whitespace
- `IP[46]` matches `IP4` or `IP6`. `[46]` matches one of characters in the group.
- `.*[0-9]` matches all the rest ending with a number.

Check this website for the detailed explanation: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nJ0vI8/1). DOn't forget in Java to use double-escaping `\\`, that's a common mistake.

```
\\d{1,3}:\\s+IP[46].*[0-9]
```

Comment: Was not aware of the IP[46] part, thanks for sharing